# Reference initialization - temporary bound to return value

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, temporary-objects

In an article about reference initialization at cppreference.com ([Lifetime of a temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)), it says:

> a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of the return expression. Such function always returns a dangling reference.

This excerpt addresses the exceptions of extending the lifetime of a temporary by binding a reference to it. What do they actually mean by that? I've thought about something like

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int&& func()
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    int&& foo = func();
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So `foo` should be referencing the temporary 42. According to the excerpt, this should be a dangling reference - but this prints 42 instead of some random value, so it works perfectly fine.

I'm sure I'm getting something wrong here, and would appreciate if somebody could resolve my confusion.

Comment: Dereferencing a dangling reference is *undefined behavior*: that includes printing 42, erasing your hard drive, or starting a nuclear war.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7211be5336782f11 But, well it's simply _undefined behavior_, everything can happen.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. So this is what they actually meant by "a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement"? And it just happens that Visual C++ compiles it in a way that 42 gets printed?

Comment: @Ruperrrt "undefined behaviour" means there is *no* definition of behaviour. It doesn't mean that the behaviour must differ from expectations (that would be a definition of sorts in itself).  Generally compilers don't go out of their way to react specially to programs with UB  , they just implement the rules for valid programs and for invalid programs the chips fall as they may.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is very good, but your compiler is not.

A temporary is often a literal value, a function return value, but also an object passed to a function using the syntax "class_name(constructor_arguments)". For example, before lambda expressions were introduced to C++, to sort things one would define some struct `X` with an overloaded `operator()` and then make a call like this:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), X());
```

In this case you expect that the lifetime of the temporary constructed with `X()` will end on the semicolon that ends the instruction.

If you call a function that expects a const reference, say, `void f(const int & n)`, with a temporery, e.g. `f(2)`, the compiler creates a temporary `int`, initailses it with `2`, and passes a reference to this temporary to the function. You expect this temporary to end its life with the semicolon in  `f(2);`.

Now consider this:

```
int && ref = 2;
std::cout << ref;
```

This code is perfectly valid. Notice, however, that here the compiler also creates a temporary object of type `int` and initalises it with `2`. This is this temporary that `ref` binds to. However, if the temporary's lifetime was limited to the instruction it is created within, and ended on the semicolon that marks the end of instruction, the next instruction would be a disaster, as `cout` would be using a dangling reference. Thus, references to temporaries like the one above would be rather impractical. This is what the "extension of the lifetime of a temporary" is needed for. I suspect that the compiler, upon seeing something like `int && ref = 2` is allowed to transform it to something like this

```
int tmp = 2;
int && ref = std::move(tmp);
std::cout << ref; // equivalent to std::cout << tmp;
```

Without lifetime expansion, this could look rather like this:

```
{
 int tmp = 2;
 int && ref = std::move(tmp);
}
std::cout << ref; // what is ref?
```

Doing such a trick in a return statement would be pointless. There's no reasonable, safe way to extend the lifetime of any object local to a function.

BTW. Most modern compilers issue a warning and reduce your function

```
int&& func()
{
    return 42;
}
```

to

```
int&& func()
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

with an immediate segfault upon any attempt to dereference the return value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and detailed answer!

Comment: There's an arrow (or triangle) pointing upwards that can be clicked  ;-)

Comment: My upvotes are not visible  because I have less than 15 reputation. :(

Comment: Perhaps you can accept the answer? It should be somewhere near these two triangles... :-)